# odbc unable to connect to MSSQL data source on OS X Lion

Tags: sql-server, macos, odbc, freetds, unixodbc

odbc `isql` was unable to connect to data source:

```
 $ isql SMS_GTWY username password -v
```

returns:

```
 [S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
 [01000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unknown host machine name.
 [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

while `tsql` is ok:

```
 $ tsql -S SERVER001 -U username -P password
```

returns:

```
 locale is "C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C"
 locale charset is "UTF-8"
 using default charset "UTF8"
 1>
```

`$ cat ~/.freetds.conf`:

```
 [SERVER001]
   host = 192.168.8.101
   port = 1433
   tds version = 8.0
   client charset = UTF8
```

`$ cat ~/.odbc.ini`:

```
  [SMS_GTWY]
  Description = SERVER001 Server
  Driver      = freetds
  Database    = SMS_GTWY
  ServerName  = SERVER001
  TDS_Version = 7.1
```

`$ cat ~/.odbcinst.ini`:

```
  [freetds]
  Description = MS SQL database access with FreeTDS
  Driver      = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
  Setup       = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
  UsageCount  = 1
```

`freetds` and `unixODBC` are install by home`brew`.

I have a similar setup on CentOS and odbc isql to mssqlserver is working fine. There is a noticable difference, I do not see a `libtdsS.so` installed on OS X.

`# cat /etc/odbcinst.ini` on CentOS:

```
 [freetds]
 Description = MS SQL database access with FreeTDS
 Driver      = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
 Setup       = /usr/lib/libtdsS.so 
 UsageCount  = 1
```

Is that the cause of problem?

p.s. `$ odbcinst -j` returns:

```
 unixODBC 2.3.1
 DRIVERS............: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.1/etc/odbcinst.ini
 SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.1/etc/odbc.ini
 FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.1/etc/ODBCDataSources
 USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/horace/.odbc.ini
 SQLULEN Size.......: 8
 SQLLEN Size........: 8
 SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

`$ odbcinst -q -d` returns:

```
 [freetds]
```

`$ odbcinst -q -s` returns:

```
 [SMS_GTWY]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`isql` works after reinstall `unixodbc` and `freetds` ( `--with-unixodbc` ):

```
 brew uninstall freetds
 brew uninstall unixodbc

 brew install unixodbc
 brew install freetds --with-unixodbc
```

Now, `$ isql -v SMS_GTWY username password` returns:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

Credit: https://gist.github.com/565440

Comment: You are a genius!  This saved my bacon while attempting to follow these otherwise useful instructions.  - http://www.acloudtree.com/how-to-install-freetds-and-unixodbc-on-osx-using-homebrew-for-use-with-ruby-php-and-perl/

Comment: Thank you.  I also had this problems.  Reinstalling

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I wasted two days on this as well but did not want to use Homebrew or MacPorts. The trick is to build FreeTDS with the the unixODBC switch. This generates the odbc driver (xxx.so) which is not generated otherwise. To start you will need
XCode and the Command Line Tools already installed. Plenty of resources on the web to show how to do that.

Here are the steps I took.

1. Download [Latest Stable FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/software.html)
2. Download [Latest Stable unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/)
3. Unpack both.
4. Note the full path to unpacked unixODBC directory.
5. From a terminal prompt navigate in to the FreeTDS directory and issue the following commands.

   ./configure **--with-unixodbc=***noted path in Step 4*
   make
   sudo make install

When complete, everything should be in /usr/local/. Your driver should be in /usr/local/lib. Edit your settings files in /usr/local/etc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who use MacPort, the only different part from above is installing FreeTDS this way:

```
sudo port install freetds +mssql +odbc +universal
```

and the driver library will be here:

```
/opt/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```